# ListFragment with multiple strings per row

Tags: java, android, android-listview, android-arrayadapter

I am new to Android development and I am trying to create a `ListFragment` that can create a `ListView` from 3 `ArrayList` objects each containing 30 Strings. Each row would contain a string from each array.

[image]

In my reading, I have found that a `ListView` is essentially created from an `ArrayAdapter`. The only examples I've seen of this however only show 1 String[] array being used (http://goo.gl/Yrkn0k, http://goo.gl/hqkdl).

How can I pass the three arrays to `ArrayAdapter` to create this `ListView`?

Answer (score 2):

ArrayAdapters can work on lists of any sort. If you need to have an ArrayAdapter operate on three separate lists at once, you will need to do two things:

- Create a new object class that is the combination of the three lists, eg. an Item class that has three fields: Title, Description, Price. Once you have a suitable object, turn your three lists into a single list of your object.
- Then you will need to create a custom adapter class that extends ArrayAdapter, overriding the `getView` method in order to properly display your items.

**Edit**

Example:

```
public class Item {
    private String title, desc, price;
    public Item(String title, String desc, String price) {
        this.title = title;
        ...
    }
    *provide standard getters and setters*
}
...
ArrayList<Item> items = new ArrayList<Item>();
for(int i = 0; i < titles.length; i++) {
    items.add(new Item(titles[i], descriptions[i], prices[i]);
}
```

Then new adapter should take the form of

```
private class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Item> {
    public CustomAdapter(ArrayList<Item> items) {
        super(getActivity(), 0, items); 
    }
...
```

Comment: I sort of follow you but am having trouble picturing it. Could you provide some code detailing at least the first point you made about combining the three lists?

Answer (score 0):

The `ArrayAdapter<T>` class is generic, so you can use it with java [Collections](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/).  To do what you're trying to do, you could use an `ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>` or just build model objects that contain your 3 string fields and use `ArrayList<YourModel>`.

For Example:

```
public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>>{

//Constructor


        @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
             ArrayList<String> current = getItem(position);

             //Do Something
        }

}
```